# Spring batch: Retry job if does not complete in particular time

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-retry, retrypolicy, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I am working on a Spring batch application where I have used `RetryTemplate` with `SimpleRetryPolicy`.

In this application, `ItemProcessor` usually takes 30-35 mins to complete a particular task. But sometimes, it takes from than 2hrs to complete that same task.

Is there a way to retry my `ItemProcessor`, if the assigned task is not completed within given time period?

I am looking for some Java/Spring in-build functionality instead of writing my own timeout logic.

Comment: How are you stopping it when it goes over the time limit?

Comment: @MichaelMinella Currently, it keeps on going until job gets finished. So the job completion is the limit right now.

Comment: Do you want to stop the job at the 35 minute mark or just rerun it again and let the first instance complete?

Comment: I want to Retry the same job with an TimedOut Exception.

Comment: @SachinMhetre, Something like this probably? https://github.com/eziztm/batch_example/blob/5e7408c0be56f359fe3e4c138844a2c7f0efd8ed/src/main/java/com/annagurban/eziz/batch/config/SingleLineBatchConfig.java#L79

Comment: @TarunLalwani, I guess this shows the time interval between retries. I am looking for TimedOut exception kind of stuff. i.e. if job is not completed in given time, then exception should be thrown

Comment: The only other info I found was this http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/106291-how-to-implement-job-timeout, see if you can implement what it says

Comment: So, what you're trying to do is to set a max timeout, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define `transactional-attributes` to a given step. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/htmlsingle/#transactionAttributes)

> Transaction attributes can be used to control the isolation, propagation, and timeout settings.

```
<step id="step1">
  <tasklet>
      <chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="2"/>
      <transaction-attributes isolation="DEFAULT"
                              propagation="REQUIRED"
                              timeout="30"/>
  </tasklet>
</step>
```

If you're using Java configuration check https://stackoverflow.com/a/23921558/1942642.