# Restart step (or job) after timeout occours

Tags: spring, spring-batch

It's possible restart a job or step automatically when timeout occurs?
I tried **retry** and **skip** (skip, because job re-run every 30 minutes, provided no error has occurred) a step, like this:

```
<step id="jobTest.step1">
  <tasklet>
    <transaction-attributes timeout="120"/>
    <chunk reader="testReader" processor="testProcessor" writer="testWriter" commit-interval="10"  retry-limit="3" >
      <retryable-exception-classes>
        <include class="org.springframework.transaction.TransactionTimedOutException"/>
       </retryable-exception-classes>
    </chunk>
    <listeners>
      <listener ref="stepListener" />
    </listeners>
  </tasklet>
</step>
```

I tried with *skip-policy* too, but I did not get satisfactory results.
I just need restart this step (or entire job) when occurs timeout .

**UPDATE**

I've tried this too, but without sucess:
[Spring batch: Retry job if does not complete in particular time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098872/spring-batch-retry-job-if-does-not-complete-in-particular-time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retry/Skip features are applicable to items within a chunk in a fault-tolerant chunk-oriented step, not at the step level or the job level. There are actually two distinct things in your requirement:

### 1. How to stop a job after a given timeout?

Apart from externally calling `JobOperator#stop` after a time out occurs, you can stop a job from within the job itself by sending a stop signal through the `StepExecution#isTerminateOnly` flag. The idea is to have access to the step execution in order to set that flag after a certain timeout. This depends on the tasklet type of the step:

#### Simple Tasklet

For a simple tasklet, you can access the step execution through the `ChunkContext`. Here is an example:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;

public class MyTasklet implements Tasklet {

    private static final int TIMEOUT = 120; // in minutes (can be turned into a configurable field through a constructor)

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        if (timeout(chunkContext)) {
            chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().setTerminateOnly();
        }
        // do some work
        if (moreWork()) {
            return RepeatStatus.CONTINUABLE;
        } else {
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        }
    }

    private boolean timeout(ChunkContext chunkContext) {
        Date startTime = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getStartTime();
        Date now = new Date();
        return Duration.between(startTime.toInstant(), now.toInstant()).toMinutes() > TIMEOUT;
    }

    private boolean moreWork() {
        return false; // TODO implement logic
    }
}
```

This tasklet will regularly check if the timeout is exceeded and stop the step (and hence the surrounding job) accordingly.

#### Chunk-oriented tasklet

In this case, you can use a step listener and set the `terminateOnly` flag in one of the lifecycle methods (`afterRead`, `afterWrite`, etc). Here is an example:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.listener.StepListenerSupport;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;

public class StopListener extends StepListenerSupport {

    private static final int TIMEOUT = 120; // in minutes (can be made configurable through constructor)

    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterChunk(ChunkContext context) { // or afterRead, or afterWrite, etc.
        if (timeout(context)) {
            this.stepExecution.setTerminateOnly();
        }
    }

    private boolean timeout(ChunkContext chunkContext) {
        Date startTime = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getStartTime();
        Date now = new Date();
        return Duration.between(startTime.toInstant(), now.toInstant()).toMinutes() > TIMEOUT;
    }
}
```

The idea is the same, you need to check the time regularly and set the flag when appropriate.

Both ways will leave your job in a `STOPPED` status which is a restartable status. Batch jobs used to be executed in a batch window and a common requirement was to stop them (gracefully) when the window is closed. The previous technique is the way to go.

The answer in [Spring batch: Retry job if does not complete in particular time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098872/spring-batch-retry-job-if-does-not-complete-in-particular-time) is not a good option IMO because it will abruptly terminate the transaction for the current chunk and leave the job in a `FAILED` status (which is a restartable status as well). However, by seeing a job in a `FAILED` status, it is not possible to distinguish a real failure from a deliberate stop. Given the requirement of deliberately wanting the job stop at a the end of the batch window, I believe that the job should be gracefully stopped and restarted in the next window.

#### 2. How to restart the job automatically after the timeout?

Now that you know how to stop a job after a timeout, you can use a `RetryTemplate` around the job launcher and re-launch the job when appropriate. Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(new SimpleRetryPolicy(3));

    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJob.class);
    JobLauncher jobLauncher = applicationContext.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
    Job job = applicationContext.getBean(Job.class);
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addDate("runtime", new Date())
            .toJobParameters();

    retryTemplate.execute((RetryCallback<JobExecution, Throwable>) retryContext -> {
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        if (jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode().equals(ExitStatus.STOPPED.getExitCode())) {
            throw new Exception("Job timeout");
        }
        return jobExecution;
    });
}
```

This will automatically re-run the job at most 3 times if it finishes with the status `STOPPED` (for example due to a timeout as shown previously).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This alternative worked fine for me.
However, the ideal one for my case, would be to force retry (or skip) when specifically the timeout occurs by _TransactionTimedOutException_ (with timeout on tasklet).

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine - Will this ensure that job/step will be restart exactly where it has stopped with the "2. How to restart the job automatically after the timeout?"