# How to use StepListenerSupport

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to stop a running job based on timeout value. I am following a post found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55049424/restart-step-or-job-after-timeout-occours/55066860#55066860), but I am not sure how you add this listener.

Here is the listener implementation

```
public class StopListener extends StepListenerSupport{
    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StopListener.class);
    private static final int TIMEOUT = 30; 
    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterChunk(ChunkContext context) {
        if (timeout(context)) {
            this.stepExecution.setTerminateOnly();
        }
    }

    private boolean timeout(ChunkContext chunkContext) {
        LOG.info("----- TIMEOUT-----");
        Date startTime = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getStartTime();
        Date now = new Date();
        return Duration.between(startTime.toInstant(), now.toInstant()).toMinutes() > TIMEOUT;
    }

}
```

Here is my step

```
@Bean
public Step dataFilterStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("dataFilterStep")
            .<UserInfo, UserInfo> chunk(10)
            .reader(dataFilterItemReader())
            .processor(dataFilterItemProcessor())
            .writer(dataFilterWriter())
            .listener(new StopListener())             
            .build();
}
```

But I am getting error saying "The method listener(Object) is ambiguous for the type SimpleStepBuilder<UserInfo,UserInfo>". A help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one hand, `StepListenerSupport` is a polymorphic object, it implements [7 interfaces](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/listener/StepListenerSupport.html). On the other hand, the step builder provides several overloaded `.listener()` methods to accept different types of listeners. That's why when you pass your `StopListener` in `.listener(new StopListener())`, the type of listener is ambiguous.

What you can do is cast the listener to the type you want, something like:

```
.listener(((ChunkListener) new StopListener()))
```

However, by following the principle of least power [1][2], I would recommend changing your `StopListener` to implement only the interface required for the functionality. In your case, you seem to want to stop the job after a given timeout in `afterChunk`, so you can make your listener implement `ChunkListener` and not extend `StepListenerSupport`.

---

- [1]: [The Rule of Least Power](https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/leastPower.html)
- [2]: [The Principle of Least Power](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-principle-of-least-power/)

Comment: Really appreciated!. This works. I used ChunkListener and its perfect. Thank you very much!